# Problem with alignment of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, vertical-alignment, jbutton

This might be a very stupid question posted at the dead of the night. I am trying to create two JButtons placed one on top of the other. However for some reason, it is not getting properly aligned. The left edge of the bottom button b2 appears slightly to the left of the left edge of top bottom b1.

Here is the code:

```
class thistrial extends JPanel implements ActionListener
 {
 ...
    public thistrial()
    {
     .....  
    add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

    //ADD THE START AND STOP BUTTONS
    Border raisedBorder = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();


    b1 = new JButton("START");
    b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,100));
    add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

    b2 = new JButton("STOP");
    b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,100));
    b2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    b2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
             add(b1);  
    add(b2);  
          .............
}
   }
/** MAIN function **/
 public static void main(String args[])

 {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setSize(398,480); 
    frame.setLocation(300,200);
    frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    //Create and set up the content pane.
    thistrial newContentPane = new thistrial();
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: you haven't given us the right sections of code. Clearly the colour information is irrelevant. And it is important to see the code where you add the buttons to your panel. Plus do you have a `setLayout`?

Comment: Sorry about that. No setLayout. I am using the default LayoutManager. I have added the actual code above.

Comment: Reformatted code; copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: The "actual code" isn't compileable so we still can't tell exactly what you are doing. If the advice to use the appropriate layout doesn't help then post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thank you all. I got it working by resizing a few controls. Since I am making the frame non-resizeable, I am not worrying about the look-and-feel if the screen changes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example extends `JPanel`, which uses `FlowLayout` by default. Instead, you might try `GridLayout`, as shown in [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the right layout manager. Your code shows none.